# Unable to retrieve value of an of an item in dropdown box on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, knockout.js

I am working on a webpage using html5 and Knockout Js and trying to insert a value into an SQL table but for some reasons I am not able to get the  id of the item selected in dropdown box

For Example, I have the following SQL table

```
ProductOrder Product
1             VS
2             Netg
5             CCast        
5             Firefox
6             App
```

Now using an Html page I have a `textbox` in which I will enter a `product name` and a `dropdown box` which has list of products in the same table.When input a `product name` and select a `product` from `dropdown` box it should insert `product name` from `textbox` and `product order` of the `product` I selected in the `dropdown` box.

I am using using the following Script

**HTML**

```
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="txbInput" placeholder="Product Name" data-bind="value: Product"/> 
    <td >
         <select data-bind="options: $root.datainput, optionsText: 'ProductName', optionsValue: 'ProductOrder',value: selectedPOrder,  optionsCaption: 'Product'">
         </select></td>
<td>
     <input type="button", onclick="ClearFields();" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="  click: add, visible: !loading()", value="Add Product"/>
</td>
```

**Knockout JS**

```
 self.selectedPOrder = ko.observable();
    var porder = this.selectedPOrder();

    self.add = function (product) {
        var payload = { ProductName: this.Product(), ProductOrder: porder };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'

        });

    }
```

For some reasons when I click on `Add`, it inserts the `product` name I enter in the textbox but it inserts 0 in the `productorder` regardless of which `product` I selected in the `dropdown box` . even the script `self.selectedPOrder()` didn't work.

```
View Model

var ProductViewModel = function (ProductContext) {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray();
    self.loading = ko.observable(true);
    self.displayMode = function (product) {
        if (product.Locked()) {
            return 'lock-template';
        } else if (product.Edit()) {
            return 'edit-template'
        }
        else {

            return 'read-template';
        }
        return 'read-template';
    }


    self.connected = ko.observable('');
    self.datainput = ko.observableArray();
    self.Product = ko.observable();

    self.selectedPOrder = ko.observable();
    //var porder = this.selectedPOrder();

    self.add = function (product) {
        var payload = { ProductName: this.Product(), ProductOrder: self.selectedPOrder() };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'

        });

    }

    self.remove = function (product) {
        var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        if (conf == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/odata/Products(' + product.Id + ')',
                type: 'DELETE',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    }
    self.edit = function (product) {
        product.Edit(true);
        ProductContext.server.lock(product.Id);
    }

    self.done = function (product) {
        product.Edit(false);
        ProductContext.server.unlock(product.Id);
    }

    self.watchModel = function (model, callback) {
        for (var key in model) {
            if (model.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isObservable(model[key]) && key !== 'Locked' && key != 'Edit') {
                self.subscribeToProperty(model, key, function (key, val) {
                    callback(model, key, val);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    self.subscribeToProperty = function (model, key, callback) {
        model[key].subscribe(function (val) {
            callback(key, val);
        });
    }

    self.modelChanged = function (model, key, val) {
        var payload = {};
        payload[key] = val;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Products(' + model.Id + ')',
            type: 'PATCH',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }


    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/odata/Products',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.products),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.datainput((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (product) {
                var obsProduct = {
                    Id: product.Id,
                    ProductName: ko.observable(product.ProductName),
                    ProductOrder: ko.observable(product.ProductOrder),
                    Edit: ko.observable(false),

                    Locked: ko.observable(product.Locked)
                }
                self.watchModel(obsProduct, self.modelChanged);
                return obsProduct;
            })));
        }
    });


    $.getJSON('/odata/Products', function (data) {
        self.products(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (product) {
            var obsProduct = {
                Id: product.Id,
                ProductName: ko.observable(product.ProductName),
                ProductOrder: ko.observable(product.ProductOrder),
                Edit: ko.observable(false),
                Locked: ko.observable(product.Locked)
            }
            self.watchModel(obsProduct, self.modelChanged);
            return obsProduct;
        }));
        self.loading(false);
    });
}

$(function () {
    var productSignalR = $.connection.product;
    var viewModel = new ProductViewModel(productSignalR);

    var findProduct = function (id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.products(), function (item) {
            if (item.Id == id) {
                return item;
            }
        });
    }

    productSignalR.client.addProduct = function (product) {
        var obsProduct = {
            Id: product.Id,
            ProductName: ko.observable(product.ProductName),
            ProductOrder: ko.observable(product.ProductOrder),
            Edit: ko.observable(false),
            Locked: ko.observable(product.Locked)
        }
        viewModel.products.push(obsProduct);
        viewModel.watchModel(obsProduct, viewModel.modelChanged);
    }

    productSignalR.client.removeProduct = function (id) {
        viewModel.products.remove(function (item) { return item.Id == id });
    }

    productSignalR.client.updatedProduct = function (id, key, value) {
        var product = findProduct(id);
        product[key](value);
    }

    productSignalR.client.lockProduct = function (id) {
        var product = findProduct(id);
        product.Locked(true);
    }

    productSignalR.client.unlockProduct = function (id) {
        var product = findProduct(id);
        product.Locked(false);
    }

    productSignalR.client.newConnection = function (id) {
        viewModel.connected(id + ' connected.');
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

**May I know where I was wrong and why is it inserting a zero**

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `$root.selectedPOrder`

```
<select data-bind=" options: $root.datainput, 
                    optionsText: 'ProductName', 
                    optionsValue: 'ProductOrder',
                    value: $root.selectedPOrder,  
                    optionsCaption: 'Product'">
</select>
```

Comment: Well I tried this too but it still inserts a 0. I use $root when it is not able reach selectPOrder from the javascript

Comment: @Dev - Can you post your whole view model then? Something else is going on here.

Comment: I have added entire view model

Answer (score -1):

Access the selected value within the self.add function like this.

```
   self.add = function (product) {
    var payload = { ProductName: this.Product(), ProductOrder: self.selectedPOrder() };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/odata/Products',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'

    });

}
```